# In angular is it possible to move a $scope property to controller scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, this

I'm now creating a nested controller, with the parent controller passing a variable in, like this:

```
app.directive('entity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'EntityShowController',
        templateUrl: '/show.html',
        controllerAs: 'showCtrl',
        scope: {
            entity: '=' // two way binding parent/child
        }
    };
})
```

And in the template I have:

```
<entity entity="parent.getSelected()"></entity>
```

Now in the child controller I can do this:

```
app.controller('EntityShowController', function($scope) {
    // this is what I should do to access the passed in two-way sync entity
    console.log($scope.entity);

    // this is what I like to achieve
    this.entity = $scope.entity;
    $scope.entity=null;
}]);
```

Is it possible to set a controller local data (`this` property) to track the parent controller data (the `$scope` property)?

I know that I can implement a `setEntity` method combined (e.g.) with `ng-click` but this is not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you are using 1.3.x version of angular you can set `bindToController` flag on the directive settings to say bind the 2-way bound scope properties to the controller instance, if you are below 1.3.x this options is not available and you would need to either directly work on scope or you would need to establish a synchronization mechanism to sync between controller instance and scope property.

```
.directive('entity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'EntityShowController',
        templateUrl: '/show.html',
        controllerAs: 'showCtrl',
        bindToController:true,
        scope: {
            entity: '=' // two way binding parent/child
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: your cntct email provided is active?

Comment: I'm using angular 1.4 and bindToController is perfect! The only (minor) drawback is that the "entity" is not available on the initialization of the controller. This makes sense, since `this` must be created by calling the controller function first, and then the scope properties are set; if you know a best practice for initialization in this case is really appreciated! :)

Comment: @giosh94mhz Yes your understanding is correct, controller instantiates before directive links and binds the 2-way binding to the directive scope and eventually binding it to the controller. It can also happen if your data is bound asyncronously. SO one pattern i use if to have an init funciton in the controller adn wrap your property dependent code in it. ANd in the directive link function (access controller as 4th argument), invoke `ctrl.init()` if data is asyncronous thensetup a one-time watch on the link function and once you get the data run the controller func.